# Docx4j - PDF Alignment Issue for Arabic characters

Tags: java, pdf-generation, docx4j, arabic-support

I'm using Docx4j 2.8.1. While generating PDF (for Arabic charcters) using Docx4j I'm getting an alignment issue. Although I have set my Arabic text in right in the .docx file but when I generate my PDF the Arabic letters get aligned to the left.

Comment: Any solutions would be welcome.Do I need to change anything in docx4j.properties file

Comment: Did you find a solution on this